# How do I use external assemblies with Microsoft Azure Function Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

The [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-reference-csharp/) says that you can put a DLL in a `bin` folder and reference it using a special `#r` syntax, however in the Azure portal I cannot find how to upload these DLLs. Is this possible, and if so, how is that supposed to be accomplished?

Comment: It looks like the questions are the same, however the answers are very different. That answer doesn't seem to apply, but the link in it mentions what I would consider the correct answer...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is possible.

You can use Kudu to upload your binaries:

1. Open the app's Kudu portal. If your Functions App's URL is `samplefunctions.azurewebsites.net`, then go to `samplefunctions.scm.azurewebsites.net`.
2. Click on the `Debug console` menu and select `PowerShell`. This will open up a PowerShell console plus a file explorer. Navigate to `D:\home\site\wwwroot`.
3. There you should see a folder which is named after your existing function. Navigate to that folder and drag-n-drop your binaries inside `bin` folder.
4. Now you can use them with `#r` directive.

I think you should also be able to configure the continuous deployment of your libraries to Functions (e.g. from a Git repo). Go to `Function app settings` -> `Configure Continuous Integration`.

Comment: So is Azure Functions in C# using ScriptCS under the hood?

Comment: I have done this but it throws error : Metadata file '<AssemblyName>' could not be found. Any idea?

Comment: This no longer works, I get: `run.csx(1,1): error CS0006: Metadata file 'Test.dll' could not be found`

Comment: After more testing, I discovered that I missed the `bin` folder step. After navigating to Kudu as described in the answer:

1. Create a `bin` folder **within** the function folder.
2. Upload the DLL files into that `bin` folder.
3. Use `#r "Test.dll"` to reference them within the csx file.

For example: `D:\home\site\wwwroot\test1\bin\Test.dll` where "test1" is the function name.

Answer (score 3):

Azure functions now has runtime support for precompiled functions.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/03/16/publishing-a-net-class-library-as-a-function-app/

You’ll need to use a web project which will provide the full development experience of IntelliSense, local debugging, and publishing to Azure. The instructions above detail how.

Answer (score 1):

You're able to deploy your functions that has some external references just doing the deploy by Visual Studio Functions Tools.

Just configure your Azure account in your visual studio deployment settings, for your azure functions and play deploy. All references will be there in your Function App on azure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Octopus Deploy (Website deployment step) to deploy a function.

The folder structure of the nuget package pushed to octopus deploy should be:

```
nuget_package.nupkg
    |--bin
        |--*.dll
    |--run.csx 
    |--function.json
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add assembly reference with a relative path. 
In portal.azure.com -> function apps, on the right hand side, View Files -> upload the dll (eg: YourDllName.dll). 
In run.csx, enter #r "./YourDllName.dll"