# Newtonsoft.Json reference complaining on Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm running an Azure Functions, called `SmsWebhook`. It calls a method in an external assembly, `AzureFunctionsSample.Services.dll` that has a reference to `Newtonsoft.Json 8.0.3`

The details of my `Run.csx` looks like:

```
#r "AzureFunctionsSample.Services.dll"
using System.Net;
using AzureFunctionsSample.Services

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    ...
}
```

Within the `Run()` method above, I create an instance and call a method in the instance. However, whenever I call that method, I receive the following error:

```
2016-05-19T13:41:45  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.
2016-05-19T13:41:46.878 Function started (Id=64fccf0c-d0ef-45ef-ac1c-7736adc94566)
2016-05-19T13:41:46.878 C# HTTP trigger function processed a request. RequestUri=https://ase-dev-fn-demo.azurewebsites.net/api/smswebhook
2016-05-19T13:41:46.878 Function completed (Failure, Id=64fccf0c-d0ef-45ef-ac1c-7736adc94566)
2016-05-19T13:41:46.894 Exception while executing function: Functions.SmsWebhook. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: One or more errors occurred. AzureFunctionsSample.Services: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).
```

I manually added the same version of `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` under the `bin` directory, but still got the same error. Why is it complaining at the `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` file?

If I move all the logics within the external assembly into the `Run.csx`, it won't complain, by the way.

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you add the following directive before your private assembly reference: #r "Newtonsoft.Json.dll" and retry?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@JustInChronicles, I'm adding this here as an answer for reference, but the expected behavior should be that indirect dependencies of private assemblies are resolved from your `bin` folder, as expected.

I put together the following test to reproduce your scenario:

- Created a simple class library with a simple type that uses Json.NET to serialize an object and return the JSON string. This assembly references Json.NET 8.0.3. The result includes the Json.NET assembly version it is using
- Created a function that references that type **only** with a `#r "DependencyWithJsonRef.dll"` and returns the result produced by the method mentioned above
- Deployed `DependencyWithJsonRef.dll` and `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` (8.0.3) to my function's `bin` folder

Invoking the function produces the expected result.

Here is the function, for reference:

```
#r "DependencyWithJsonRef.dll"

using System.Net;

public static string Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    var myType = new DependencyWithJsonRef.TestType();
    return myType.GetFromJson();
}
```

As you can see, no explicit reference to indirect dependencies (Json.NET) required.

This is the output I get:

```
{
    "Prop1":"Test",
    "Prop2":1,
    "AssemblyName": "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"
}
```

**Quick note:** One thing you may want to check, particularly if you've updated that dependency while developing your function is that assembly resultion results were not cached. A sure way to make sure you're starting with a clean slate is to (after you deploy your function and assemblies) go to Kudu and kill the **non-scm** w3wp process to see if that helps. I'd be curious to know if that does the trick as there are a few things we can to to improve this if it does.

Comment: Thanks! After I restart the function app itself (because basically it's a web app), I don't have to have a file reference, `#r "Newtonsoft.Json.dll"`, but `#r "Newtonsoft.Json"` was enough, if I need to use it in the `run.csx` file. If I don't need it, the reference was not necessary.

Comment: But, if I don't put the `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` assembly into the `bin` directory, it gets an error. I'm still curious, why I should have the assembly, even though it's already internally referenced.

Comment: You shouldn't need the file reference if you're referencing the shared assembly (simple name), if you need a specific version, though, you'd place the file in your bin folder and reference with the extension.

Answer (score 20):

Json.Net can be simply reference adding this line at the top of your `Run.csx` file :

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
```

See this article if you want to know which assemblies are automatically added by the Azure Functions hosting environment:

- [Azure Functions C# developer reference](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-reference-csharp/#referencing-external-assemblies)

Otherwise, if you want to use a specific version of Json.Net, you should probably add a reference to Json.Net using nuget package:

- [How can I use NuGet packages in my Azure Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411536/how-can-i-use-nuget-packages-in-my-azure-functions)

So you need to add a Project.json file that look like this:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.3"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

If your external dependency references `Newtonsoft.Json` without using a nuget package, you can have a look at this post that explains how to upload your binaries:

- [How do I use external assemblies with Microsoft Azure Function Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36559509/how-do-i-use-external-assemblies-with-microsoft-azure-function-apps)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case.I did add `#r "Newtonsoft.Json"` and `using Newtonsoft.Json;` in my `run.csx` file, even though these are not directly used in the file. I also added `project.json` with the NuGet reference like you suggested, but this didn't help me.

Comment: My issue is that the Json.NET library couldn't be loaded, even though it's there.

Comment: do you have the exact exception that is thrown ?

Comment: That is why I was asking about a file based reference (with the DLL extension) as that would trigger a private assembly load, as opposed to the shared assembly that doesn't match the version you expect. Can you give that a try?

Comment: Also, if you continue to see the issue after making that chang, please try to restart your  site under settings.

Comment: @FabioCavalcante I did `#r "Newtonsoft.Json.dll"` and still doesn't work. However, it seems that I found what the issue here I have.

Comment: Do you mind sharing? I just finished testing your original scenario (dependency with a reference to Json.net 8.0.3) and with both deployed to bin, it works as expected. The Functions runtime will attempt to resolve private assembly dependencies from the private location. Is it possible you were missing the right assembly version when you first tried?

Comment: @FabioCavalcante I wrote another answer, instead of leaving here as a comment. Please have a look and correct me, if I missed anything.

Answer (score 2):

After some trial-and-error approach. I found what the issue was here.

@FabioCavalcante gave me a hint using a file-based reference,

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
```

It didn't work actually. I've copied those four files to Azure Functions' `bin` directory:

- `AzureFunctionsSample.Services.dll`
- `AzureFunctionsSample.Services.pdb`
- `Newtonsoft.Json.dll`
- `Newtonsoft.Json.xml`

It still gave me the same error, even though I did the file-based reference. Then, I found another file, `AzureFunctionsSample.Services.dll.config` that actually defines assembly binding redirects like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

After I copied this config file to the Azure Functions' `bin` directory, it worked!

---

**Lessons Learnt**

- Use the file-based reference for `Newtonsoft.Json`, `#r "Newtonsoft.Json.dll"`, if your external assembly also has a reference to it.
- Make sure that the assembly binding redirect configuration exists in Azure Functions' `bin` directory.

Correct me, if I'm still wrong.

Cheers,

Comment: I'm glad this is working for you! As mentioned in my previous comment, those steps *shouldn't* be required, though. Just having your direct dependency #r reference in the function and making sure the expected version of Json.NET is deployed into your bin folder should work as expected. Not sure if you want to go through those steps, but it would be interesting to have the setup described above, making sure you restart the host (to ensure a clean slate with assembly resolution) to see if that works. As mentioned, I reproduced your scenario and it worked as described here.

Comment: Another small clarification; you **do not** need to add explicit references to indirect dependencies. So the `#r "Newtonsoft.Json.dll"` (or with simple name) shouldn't be required at all.

Comment: @FabioCavalcante Do you know how to avoid `Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.15.0`? Any place I can add the binding redirects?