# How can I Parse Json in a Azure Function

Tags: json, azure, azure-functions

"I have create a Azure Function in this function I call an API that returns JSON. I want to parse this JSON to an object so I can use it in the function. I cannot not use Newton.JSON as the function seems not to know this.
How can I parse the JSON?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Newtonsoft.Json reference complaining on Azure Functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335321/newtonsoft-json-reference-complaining-on-azure-functions)

Comment: Json.NET *is* added to the Azure Functions environment. Please post your code. It's impossible to guess what's wrong without it. Most likely, you are missing the assembly reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Azure Function your first you need to add a reference to NewtonSoft.JSON. You can do this via "Newtonsoft.Json". Do not forget the quotes!!!

Than you can use the normal serialization via newtonsoft:

```
var response = await client.GetAsync("<url>");
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var o= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<"Type">(json);
```

Answer (score 44):

Here is a complete Azure Function source code for serializing/deserializing objects using JsonNet:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    dynamic body = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var e = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EventData>(body as string);
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(e));
}

public class EventData
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

Sample input (request body):

```
{
    "Category": "Azure Functions",
    "Action": "Run",
    "Label": "Test"
}
```

Sample output:

```
"{\"Category\":\"Azure Functions\",\"Action\":\"Run\",\"Label\":\"Test\"}"
```

Answer (score 7):

You answer above is returning a string and not JSON.  I would suggest that you modify your answer as follows:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    dynamic body = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var e = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EventData>(body as string);
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, e);
}
```

This will return the Sample output without the JSON escapes:

```
{"Category":"Azure Functions","Action":"Run","Label":"Test"}
```

Answer (score 2):

As for .Net Core 2 :

```
string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
```

and then you can deserialize it:

```
dynamic jObject= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
```

and to complete your answer (convert to object):

```
JToken jCategory = jObject;
var whatever = jCategory["yourkeyiteminjson"].ToObject<YourObjectType>();
```

i.e to show you how flexible it is:

Let's say for this Json input:

```
{"companyId": "123456","payments": [{"id": "31212"},{"id": "31212"},{"id": "3"}],"miFees": [{"id": "452"},{"id": "254"}]}
```

You can do as follow:

```
var companyId = jObject["companyId"].ToString();
var payments = jCategory["payments"].ToObject<List<PaymentTransaction>>();
```