# Azure Function Object Return not returning correct nested values

Tags: c#, .net-core, postman, azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an API which expected to return result as below (which holds the data fetched from Cosmos DB)

```
public class ConsumerResponse
    {
        public string ObjectId { get; set; }
        public string ConsumerType { get; set; }
        public object Data { get; set; }
    }
```

I am using postman to test this API. Below is the API function which returns CustomerResponse object

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("{container}/{consumerType}/{objectId}")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ConsumerResponse), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ErrorResponse), (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ErrorResponse), (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)]
    public async Task<ConsumerResponse> Get(string container , string consumerType, string objectId)
    {
        var response =  await _messageProcessingService.GetAsync(container, consumerType, objectId);
        return response;
    }
```

When I debug the code, I can see all the valid data mapped to each propery in CustomerResponse class. The "Data" is nested object. However when I call this API in Postman the nested values of "Data" object becomes empty as below

```
{
    "objectId": "8bea9894-8685-46e4-8637-5614e624b05e",
    "consumerType": "Patient",
    "data": {
        "name": [
            [
                []
            ],
            [
                []
            ],
            [
                []
            ],
            [
                []
            ]
        ],
        "gender": [],
        "birthDate": [],
        "countryCode": [],
        "isActive": [],
        "consumerConsent": [],
        "accountStatus": [
            [
                [
                    []
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

However if I change the data type of "Data" as string then I am getting result as below

```
{
    "objectId": "8bea9894-8685-46e4-8637-5614e624b05e",
    "consumerType": "Patient",
    "data": "{\r\n  \"name\": {\r\n    \"use\": \"Official\",\r\n    \"surname\": \"Dope\",\r\n    \"firstName\": \"Johny\",\r\n    \"prefix\": \"Mr.\"\r\n  },\r\n  \"gender\": \"Male\",\r\n  \"birthDate\": \"1991-02-02\",\r\n  \"countryCode\": \"IN\",\r\n  \"isActive\": false,\r\n  \"consumerConsent\": true,\r\n  \"accountStatus\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"startDate\": \"2021-09-08T09:27:21.1946786+10:00\"\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}"
}
```

How do I get the values for nested structure when I use Object data type?

-Alan-

Comment: Not a lot to work with here. Also, the whole object thing you have going on with `public object Data` is very suspicious

Comment: can you change the Object to the Class of that type object and try?

Comment: So, how about just using string rather than object? It seems to be a data convert issue, and there aren't many choices to try here.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all values as the data type as string because it gets the key value pair so you can check here to convert to json [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16079629/15997690)

In a Azure Function you need to add a reference to `NewtonSoft.JSON`

`Newtonsoft.Json` library is a [special case](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-reference-csharp/). You can include it by adding this at the top of the script file:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

and add the below lines of code to get the json nested values.

```
var response = await client.GetAsync("<url>");

var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var obj= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<"Type">(json);
```

Refer here for more info [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38095628/15997690) & [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38943858/how-do-i-return-json-from-an-azure-function)