# Type or Namespace name not found in Azure Functions

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to push some simulated data to azure iot hub and store the data received to iot hub in a mongo db using azure functions(C#). Receiveing iot hub messages up to azure functions is working. when I am trying to push them to mongo db as follows, it gives the following error.  I followed [this](https://medium.com/@avirup171/azure-iot-hub-azure-function-azure-cosmos-db-walkthrough-cc30d12d1055) tutorial while doing this.

**my run.csx**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using MongoDB.Bson.IO;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public static void Run(string myIoTHubMessage, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# IoT Hub trigger function processed a message: {myIoTHubMessage}");
    string deviceId="",data="";
    var raw_obj=JObject.Parse(myIoTHubMessage);
    deviceId=(string)raw_obj["device_id"];
    data=(string)raw_obj["Data"];
    Cosmos cosmos= new Cosmos(deviceId,data);
    cosmos.pushData();
}

//CosmosDB class
public class Cosmos
{
    string deviceId="",data="";
    public BsonDocument document = new BsonDocument();
    public Cosmos(string deviceId, string data)
    {
        this.deviceId=deviceId;
        this.data=data;
    }
    public void pushData()
    {
        MainAsync().Wait();
    }
    public async Task MainAsync()
    {
        string connectionString = 
    @"mongodb://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(new MongoUrl(connectionString));
        settings.SslSettings = new SslSettings() { EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12};
        var mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
        IMongoDatabase db = mongoClient.GetDatabase("iot");
        var icollection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(deviceId);
        document.Add("Data",data);
        await icollection.InsertOneAsync(document);
    }

}
```

**my project.json file**

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Newtonsoft.Json": "10.0.3",
        "System.ServiceModel.Primitives":"4.4.0",
        "MongoDB.Bson": "2.4.0",
        "MongoDB.Driver": "2.4.0",
        "MongoDB.Driver.Core": "2.4.0"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

when I ran the code it gives following error

```
2018-10-10T18:34:25.990 [Error] Function compilation error
2018-10-10T18:34:26.119 [Error] run.csx(3,27): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Description' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ServiceModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2018-10-10T18:34:26.242 [Error] run.csx(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MongoDB' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2018-10-10T18:34:26.332 [Error] run.csx(5,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MongoDB' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2018-10-10T18:34:26.435 [Error] run.csx(6,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MongoDB' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2018-10-10T18:34:26.548 [Error] run.csx(7,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MongoDB' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2018-10-10T18:34:26.666 [Error] run.csx(10,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2018-10-10T18:34:26.771 [Error] run.csx(11,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2018-10-10T18:34:26.828 [Warning] run.csx(13,48): warning CS0618: 'TraceWriter' is obsolete: 'Will be removed in an upcoming version. Use ILogger instead.'
2018-10-10T18:34:26.946 [Error] run.csx(28,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BsonDocument' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2018-10-10T18:34:27.058 [Error] run.csx(17,17): error CS0103: The name 'JObject' does not exist in the current context
2018-10-10T18:34:27.201 [Error] run.csx(28,40): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BsonDocument' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2018-10-10T18:34:27.304 [Error] run.csx(42,5): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MongoClientSettings' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2018-10-10T18:34:27.431 [Error] run.csx(42,36): error CS0103: The name 'MongoClientSettings' does not exist in the current context
2018-10-10T18:34:27.632 [Error] Executed 'Functions.EventHubTriggerCSharp1' (Failed, Id=32bc6c5d-73fa-4082-b74b-c86a901f6656)
```

Can someone help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 6):

Problem is caused by the difference of Function runtime.

The tutorial you follow creates function on ~1 runtime where code targets at .NET Framework , while the one you create is on ~2 runtime which runs on .NET Core env. When we create a new Function app its runtime is set to ~2 by default now.

Solution is to set `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` to `~1` in Application settings on portal. Then click `View Files` on function panel and edit `function.json` to make it work in v1--change `eventHubName` to `path`. See [event hub trigger configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#trigger---configuration).

And some improvements, remove those not used in the context along with `System.ServiceModel.Primitives` in project.json. `Newtonsoft.Json` assembly exists but is not added to host, need to reference it explicitly.

1. assembly and namespace using

   ```
   #r "Newtonsoft.Json"

   using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
   using MongoDB.Bson;
   using MongoDB.Driver;
   using System.Security.Authentication;
   ```
2. project.json.

   ```
   {
     "frameworks": {
       "net46":{
         "dependencies": {
           "MongoDB.Bson": "2.7.0",
           "MongoDB.Driver": "2.7.0"
         }
       }
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: when I changed `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION to ~1` it gives errror `Function (EventHubTriggerCSharp1) Error: Can't figure out which ctor to call.`

Comment: @KrishanMadushanka Sorry for my omission, you also need click `View files` to edit `function.json`, change `eventHubName` to `path`.

Comment: solved the problem by using javascript to write azure function

Comment: @KrishanMadushanka Great, glad you made it. You can post your answer if it's not too much trouble.

Comment: Sure I will post the answer. Anyway thanks for following up

Answer (score 2):

If you are using run.csx you need to "import" your referenced assemblies by using #r.

[The example below is from the documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-external-assemblies)

```
#r "System.Web.Http"

using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
```

Comment: importing #r "Newtonsoft.Json" works but #r "System.Runtime.Serialization" and #r "MongoDB" do not work :/

Comment: Are you sure the assemblies (and their dependencies) are all uploaded too? See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36559509/how-do-i-use-external-assemblies-with-microsoft-azure-function-apps

Comment: I have added them in project.json file

Comment: Please read the link I pasted in my last comment. You need to UPLOAD them to the Azure Functions instance as well.